# python package to find closest zip code in a list of zip codes for a given zip code

Tags: python

There is  a way to calculate distance between two locations knowing their lat, lon  using  haversine function.
Just wondering if there is a package in python to help to find the closest zip code within a list of zip codes for a given zip code.
For example, I have a zip code 35670, I  have a zip_list :[24504,18509,95134...]. How could I find the zip in zip_list which is closest to 35670?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the distance between 2 points is rather simple since you can use a [library](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.distance) for that, e.g.:

```
from geopy import distance
newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796)
cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391)
print(distance.distance(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles)
538.39044536
```

Now the tricky part is to get positional data, e.g. latitude & longitude for a zip code. You can search for services which provide that for the territory you are looking for, e.g. for the USA [here](https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/us-zip-code-latitude-and-longitude/table/).

I also saw that [Nominatim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62873106/11971785) might be able to provide this information but I have not yet used it.